# how to remove kubuntu plasma 5 dekstop?

Tags: system-installation, uninstall, sudo

I installed KDE 5 Plasma using this command

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install kubuntu-plasma5-desktop
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

How to remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next
```